# How to change scale of a plot with Maplotlib and add increments?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am making a simple plot in Python with Matplotlib that shows populations of different regions over time.  I have a CSV file that has columns of each region's population over the years, so the years is on the x-axis and population is on the y-axis. The plot looks okay except the y-axis. As you can see in the image, every single population value is included on the y-axis, which is too many values and is unnecessary. I would like to y-axis to have some increments (such as 100 million). Is there a simple way to do that or would I have to manually add my own increments?

And I tried to scale it linearly and logarithmic but I would still prefer to have increments on the y-axis.

This is what the plot looks like right now.
[image]

(I took out unnecessary code such as legend and formatting):

```
data2 = pd.read_csv('data02_world.csv')

for region in data2:
    if region != 'Year':
        plt.plot(data2.Year, data2[region], marker='.', label=region)

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Population')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation? You are looking for ticks and ticklabels...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do with pandas:

```
data2 = pd.read_csv('data02_world.csv')
data2.set_index('Year', inplace=True)
data2.plot()
```

if you would like to adopt matplotlib plt.yticks is what you need